# ActiveMQ Artemis divert logging

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a way to log active mq Artemis diverts? So you can see which divert was applied to a given message? I can't seem to find this in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate TRACE logging for org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl.  This will log a message for each diverted message.  See the logging code [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/DivertImpl.java#L90).

Comment: very useful indeed.

Comment: Hi. I have tried to use this. Not getting it to work. How do you set the logging.properties to use this option? Using 2.9.0.

Comment: You should create a new question about how to adjust the logging configuration.

Comment: Hi. I will do that. But it is the same question as this question. So it will be duplicate questions.

Comment: The question about divert logging is already answered. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to know how to adjust the `logging.properties` for a particular logger (e.g. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl`), right? Those are different questions.

Answer (score 1):

An option could be found here in docs:

> Diverts can also be configured to apply a Transformer. If specified,
>   all diverted messages will have the opportunity of being transformed
>   by the Transformer.

Since Transformer is a class you could implement and trace with a Logger implementation, just without touching the message.

Comment: thanks that's the approach I have taken. I was wondering if there is something already in artemis that I have missed. Seems like something artemis would provide, to trace message lineage.